# How to update a text box continously without halting the button in windows form application C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling, multitasking

I need to update my text box continuously after clicking the button but the button should perform its remaining task as it is.

simple is that when click event is performed then Text box should not wait for the completion of click event but to start updating its text continuously.

sample code

```
using System.threading;

namespace name
{
    public class sA
    {
        public void th()
        {
           textbox.invoke(new MethodInvoke(()=> textbox.AppendText("hello\n")));
        }

        private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           thread cThread=new thread(th);
           cThread.start();

           while(true)
           {
               // do any thing
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Important :: when it performs the event " Cthread.start();" text box should immediately start updating the text while the remaining functions of click event like "while loop" should perform in parallel.

[image]

Comment: Do *not* use loops on the UI thread.  An obvious solution is to just swap these two pieces of code.  Move the while() loop to the th() method, move the Text assignment to the Click event handler.  Leverage the BackgroundWorker class.

Answer (score 5):

IF this is inside Windows Forms.. then add `Application.DoEvents();` anywhere in the loop
e.g.

```
private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   thread cThread=new thread(th);
   cThread.start();
   while(true)
   {
     // do any thing   
     textbox.Invalidate();
     Application.DoEvents(); // Releases the current thread back to windows form
                          // NOTE Thread sleep different in Application.DoEvents();
                          //Application.DoEvents() is available only in System.Windows.Forms
   }
}
```

Hope this help you although late.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `while(true)` block has to happen on another thread as well.

Right now its blocking the UI thread from performing any updates.

Method th() is running on a background thread but the call to Invoke can't run until the UI thread is available again.

Comment: couldn't find what I need... :-(

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to keep updating the TextBox's text while the button click procedure is running inside it's "while" loop. You didn't really specify where will the textbox be updated from, but I will assume that it is coming from the code inside your "while" loop.

As "akatakritos" has stated, your while loop inside the button click is the reason why your application is halting. That happens because the while loop is blocking the User Interface (UI) Thread.

What you should be doing is moving the code inside your "while" loop to run inside a different thread, and use the button click to start this new thread.

Here is a way to do this, maybe not the best, but it will do what you need:

Create a new class:

```
public class ClassWithYourCode
{
    public TextBox TextBoxToUpdate { get; set; }
    Action<string> updateTextBoxDelegate;

    public ClassWithYourCode()
    { }

    public void methodToExecute()
    {
        bool IsDone = false;
        while (!IsDone)
        {
            // write your code here. When you need to update the 
            // textbox, call the function:
            // updateTextBox("message you want to send");
            // Below you can find some example code:

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                updateTextBox(string.Format("Iteration number: {0}", i));
            }

            // Don't forget to set "IsDone" to "true" so you can exit the while loop!
            IsDone = true;
        }

        updateTextBox("End of method execution!");
    }

    private void updateTextBox(string MessageToShow)
    {
        if (TextBoxToUpdate.InvokeRequired)
        {
            updateTextBoxDelegate = msgToShow => updateTextBox(msgToShow);
            TextBoxToUpdate.Invoke(updateTextBoxDelegate, MessageToShow);
        }
        else
        {
            TextBoxToUpdate.Text += string.Format("{0}{1}", MessageToShow, Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

}
```

and, inside your button1_Click method, you can add the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClassWithYourCode myCode = new ClassWithYourCode();
    myCode.TextBoxToUpdate = textBox1;

    Thread thread = new Thread(myCode.methodToExecute);
    thread.Start();
}
```

Now, your "while" loop is executing inside a new thread and, whenever you need to update the textbox, you do so from the UI thread, because you cannot update Windows Forms controls from a thread other than the UI thread.

Comment: its so nice of you but sorry for this time i couldn't get what i need from  it.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. You say your textbox will be updated continuously, but where exactly will it be updated from?